# Eclipse java code style formatter profile location

Tags: eclipse, formatter

I am trying to find out where the code style formatter profiles are saved.
I have three profiles, but I need to know where they are located on my hard drive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you need is to export theses files before importing them.

```
 Eclipse > Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter:
```

- Choose Active Profile from the list
- Edit
- Export
- Locate the directory you want to save it.

[image: Export Eclipse Formatter Profile]

Answer (score 24):

They are located in your workspace in these files

```
...\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs 
...\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
```

Comment: I can only see my current configuration in here, but not the other predefined profiles.

Comment: Yes, only the profiles you have created will be saved here. Why do you need the built in profiles? They will always be there in Eclipse...

Comment: I see profiles created by the person who set up my Eclipse. I would like to see where these profiles are located at.