# Missing java code formatter from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, eclipse-formatter

I have the latest eclipse with jdk 16. I have a custom code formatter style that I use. The code formatter seems to be gone from preferences|java|code style. Instead I have only preferences|java|code style.

I managed to import an old .epf file, but it does not seem to have done anything.

Does anyone know what happened to it?

Is there a way to find it or add it back in?

I am using the dark theme from [devstyle](https://www.genuitec.com/products/devstyle/download/).

*Maybe* related to [Eclipse preferences removed on Eclipse restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576310/eclipse-preferences-removed-on-eclipse-restart).

Edit 1: Looking at @LMC's suggestion. [Eclipse java code style formatter profile location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634366/eclipse-java-code-style-formatter-profile-location/13638154). I was able to find and import my preferences file, but could still not find "formatter" anywhere. Managed to import my latest preferences from my only  .epf file, but that was only 5 lines long. I have many .xml files that are saved preferences. Is there any way to load them? And it looks like that made even more preferences go away.

Exporting preferences *does* have formatting info. Importing the preferences that I just made gives me the devstyle restart nag.

I still see one page for the each main preference. I will try more experiments. ...

Edit 2: I installed a fresh copy of Installer 2021‑06 R in a *different* directory. Seems like all of the preferences are there. However, I have no dark theme. Looks like it may be devstyle problem.

Edit 3: I installed the spectrum dark theme and it works fine. The formatter option is back again and *all* of my preferences were present. So it's not clear what the problem was.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13638154/2834978)

Comment: Try to run previous version of Eclipse and export as much as you can from there. Then import on new version.